# xjc inverse package name order

Tags: jaxb, xjc

I run the following command

```
java -jar "C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.jvnet.jaxbw.eclipse_1.1.0\lib\jaxb-xjc.jar" -d src  -catalog xsd\catalog.cat xsd\componentsData.xsd
```

xsd\componentsData.xsd contain the following lines:

```
xmlns:txtColor="com.my.company.product.jaxb.TextColor"
xmlns="com.my.company.product.jaxb.componentsData"
targetNamespace="com.my.company.product.jaxb.componentsData"

<xsd:import
schemaLocation="TextColor.xsd"
namespace="com.my.company.product.jaxb.TextColor"/>
```

xsd\TextColor.xsd contain the following

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.0"
         xmlns="com.my.company.product.jaxb.TextColor"
         targetNamespace="com.my.company.product.jaxb.TextColor"
         >
```

this is my catalog:

```
<!DOCTYPE catalog
  PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD Entity Resolution XML Catalog V1.0//EN"
       "http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/release/1.0/catalog.dtd">
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">

<system
    systemId="com.my.company.product.jaxb.TextColor.TextColor.xsd"
    uri="TextColor"/>
```

and my files got generated in the following path - **THE ORDER IS INVERTED WHY ?**:
componentsData.jaxb.product.company.my.com

and

TextColor.jaxb.product.company.my.com

if i add the following argument files got generated in the right order but the catalog.cat don't seem to be taken in consideration

```
-p com.my.company.product.jaxb.componentsData
```

Comment: OK, i got the answer, i needed to use binding file.
But is this possible to do it throw xjc eclipse plugin.
I can't post the answer now - so i'll post it later.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a binding file (-b option with xjc)

```
<jaxb:bindings
   xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   version="2.1">

<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="componentsData.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="com.my.company.product.jaxb.componentsData"/>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>

<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="TextColor.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="com.my.company.product.jaxb.TextColor"/>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

But i still have a question:
I Started using xjc because i didn't succeed doing it with eclipse, how can i do it with eclipse gui